# CASE syntax with addition and greater/less operators

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm getting syntax errors on the `>`,`<`, and `=` operators here and I'm really not sure why. I've tried enclosing `reorder_quantity + in_stock` in `()` and I still get the same errors. What am I missing here?

I'm trying to use the following code to generate a list of amounts that I should order for certain products. Im using SQL to do so because I order the products in oz. but they are inventoried in mLs, and my POS can't handle the conversion natively.

```
select itemnum, itemname, in_stock, reorder_level, 
    case reorder_quantity + in_stock 
        when reorder_quantity + in_stock > reorder_level 
           then reorder_quantity/29.5735                                                
        when reorder_quantity + in_stock = reorder_level 
           then reorder_quantity/29.5735*2
        when reorder_quantity + in_stock < reorder_level 
           then reorder_quantity/29.5735*2
        else 0 
        end as order_amount_oz

from inventory 

group by itemnum 

and in_stock < reorder_level
```

Comment: Why did you need to use `group by` when you didn't use any aggregate function?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and exepct result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing the two types of `case` syntax:

1. `case expression when value1 then output1 when value2 then output2 else output3 end`
2. `case when expression = value1 then output1 when expression = value2 then output2 else output3 end`

together, which is a syntax error. Chose one or the other.

Try this refactoring and simplification that‘s the same as your intention:

```
reorder_quantity / 29.5735 * 
    case when reorder_quantity + in_stock > reorder_level then 1 else 2 end as order_amount_oz
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you can try to remove `group by` and using parentheses

```
select itemnum, itemname, in_stock, reorder_level, 
    case 
        when (reorder_quantity + in_stock) > reorder_level 
           then reorder_quantity/29.5735                                                
        when (reorder_quantity + in_stock) = reorder_level 
           then reorder_quantity/(29.5735*2)
        when (reorder_quantity + in_stock) < reorder_level 
           then reorder_quantity/(29.5735*2)
        else 0 
        end as order_amount_oz

from inventory
```

Comment: btw you don't need the brackets around the additions